# Itemize colored bullet - no shadow

Tags: color, itemize

There's a way to make itemize bullet blue as the text? Only color, no shadow

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[
  a4paper,
  margin=15mm,
  bindingoffset=2mm,
  heightrounded,
]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareMathOperator{\sen}{sen}

\begingroup\setlength{\fboxsep}{2pt}
\colorbox{white}{%
  \begin{varwidth}[t]{\textwidth}
  INTEGRALI
  \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]

  \item $\int a\, dx = ax$

  \item \textcolor{blue}{$\int x^{n}\, dx = \dfrac{1}{n}x^{n+1}$}

  \item $\int \cos x\, dx = \sen x$

  \item \textcolor{blue}{$\int \sen x\, dx = -\cos x$}

  \item $\int \dfrac{1}{x}\, dx = \ln x$

  \item \textcolor{blue}{$\int \ln x\, dx = \int \ln x \cdot 1\, dx $}

  \item $\int f'[g(x)] \cdot g'(x)\, dx = f[g(x)] + c$

  \item \textcolor{blue}{$\int f(x) \cdot g'(x)\, dx = f(x) \cdot g(x) - \int f'(x) \cdot g(x)\, dx $}

  \end{itemize}
  \end{varwidth}%
}\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Set the `label` option `itemize` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[italian]{babel}
    \usepackage[
      a4paper,
      margin=15mm,
      bindingoffset=2mm,
      heightrounded,
    ]{geometry}

    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{microtype}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage{varwidth}
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \usepackage{hyperref}

    \newif\ifblueitem
    \blueitemtrue
    \newcommand\blueitem{\blueitemtrue\item}
    \newcommand\blackitem{\blueitemfalse\item}

    \DeclareMathOperator{\sen}{sen}
    \begin{document}

    \begingroup
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{2pt}
    \colorbox{white}{%
      \begin{varwidth}[t]{\textwidth}
      INTEGRALI
      \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*,label={\ifblueitem\color{blue}\else\color{black}\fi\textbullet}]

      \blackitem $\int a\, dx = ax$

      \blueitem \textcolor{blue}{$\int x^{n}\, dx = \dfrac{1}{n}x^{n+1}$}

      \blackitem $\int \cos x\, dx = \sen x$

      \blueitem \textcolor{blue}{$\int \sen x\, dx = -\cos x$}

      \blackitem $\int \dfrac{1}{x}\, dx = \ln x$

      \blueitem \textcolor{blue}{$\int \ln x\, dx = \int \ln x \cdot 1\, dx $}

      \blackitem $\int f'[g(x)] \cdot g'(x)\, dx = f[g(x)] + c$

      \blueitem \textcolor{blue}{$\int f(x) \cdot g'(x)\, dx = f(x) \cdot g(x) - \int f'(x) \cdot g(x)\, dx $}

      \end{itemize}
      \end{varwidth}%
    }
    \endgroup
    \end{document}
```

[image]